# Pandas read part of a delimited txt file

Tags: python, pandas, input, text-files, delimiter

So I have a txt file from the earthquake experiment machine output:

```
23      (-9.144,  2.7432,  0) [HybridDamper/Floor 1 Disp m,--,--] #ffffff
24      (-4.572,  0,       0) #ffffff
# End Node section
===
# Begin Member section
gl gr #eeeeee
23 D1 yellow
```

So there is a # End Node section, ===, #Begin Member secion that separates two parts of the output.
I want to create two dataframes, one for the above part, and the other one for the below part.

Without manually edit the output file from machine (which is not easy when the structure is big), is it possible to let pandas recognize the part separator (e.g., these lines start from #, =) from the .txt file?

Thank you guys!
Best
Shawn

Comment: What do you expect the columns to look like after importing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

with open('mytext.txt') as f:
    txt = f.read()

marker = '# End Node section\n===\n# Begin Member section'
txt1, txt2 = txt.split(marker)

df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt1), header=None, sep='|')
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt2), header=None, sep='\s+', engine='python')
```

Comment: Hi, I expect the column to be like as: For the first part, sep the () and only keep the first half, e.g, 24 -4.572 0 0; for the second part, keep all the columns, e.g, 23 D1 yellow

Comment: I have a function where it can edit the parse rule and I can rid of ", ()[]", and then I just keep the [0,1,2,3] columns for the first part to rid the latter half.